# Get original filename from process id

Tags: c++, winapi, filenames

Could anyone share an idea how to get original filename of file from process id?

I tried with function:

```
bool getProcessOriginalFilename(LPSTR lpszFilePath)
{   
    DWORD dwDummy; 
    DWORD dwFVISize = GetFileVersionInfoSize( lpszFilePath , &dwDummy ); 
    LPBYTE lpVersionInfo = new BYTE[dwFVISize]; 
    GetFileVersionInfo( lpszFilePath , 0 , dwFVISize , lpVersionInfo ); 
    UINT uLen; 
    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *lpFfi; 
    VerQueryValue( lpVersionInfo , _T("\\") , (LPVOID *)&lpFfi , &uLen ); 
    printf( "Original filename: %x\n" , lpFfi->OriginalFilename); 
    delete [] lpVersionInfo; 
    return true;
}
```

but there is an error in `lpFfi->OriginalFilename`:
`struct tagVS_FIXEDFILEINFO' has no member named 'OriginalFilename'`

I have also no idea how to get filepath from processID cause Tlhelp32 entry returns only current filename without path and process id.

Comment: [`GetModuleFileNameEx function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: To add on, the process handle is easily retrieved via `OpenProcess`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So only fixing the function left.

Comment: Note: A **PID** is not the same, and not interchangable with, a **Process Handle**. The question says process IDs (which today i need to solve). `GetModuleFileNameEx` takes a process handle.